# Path with relative points in SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design

I have got svg with flexible height and width.

I'm trying to produce code equivalent to this:

```
<div id="svg-container">
  <svg width='100%' height='100%' viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" style='background-color: yellow'>

    <path 
      style="fill:none;stroke:blue;stroke-width:5;"
      d="M0% 10% L50% 10% L50% 90% L100% 90%"          <-here is the problem
    />

  </svg> 
</div>
```

So when I scale `#svg-container` i will get:

[image]

But since I can't create path with percent coordinates the best I can do is: ([JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/h0c5vgjw/)

```
<div id="svg-container">
  <svg width='100%' height='100%' viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" style='background-color: yellow'>

    <path 
      style="fill:none;stroke:blue;stroke-width:5;"
      d="M0 10 L50 10 L50 90 L100 90"               
    />

  </svg> 
</div>
```

Which gives me this results:

[image]

On the second picture you can see problem with stretched `stroke-width`.

**My question is: how to achieve behavior like on the first picture?**

I'm not looking for JavaScript answers and breaking path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want a style of [vector-effect](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGMobile12/painting.html#NonScalingStroke): non-scaling-stroke

Note that not all UAs implement this but Chrome and Firefox certainly do.

Comment: Yes! It works. Just one line of code fixed it: http://jsfiddle.net/2fp9tLzm/
Do you now if IE11 support it?

Comment: IE11 does not support vector-effect

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to say I think you will only be able to do this with JavaScript, even if this is not the answer that you're looking for. What is happening is that you are first generating the SVG path, then resizing it afterward so the image becomes stretched.

To use JavaScript you can use (browser.width/100)*10 to get 10%, for example, and this should work for all sizes of browser screen.

How are you re-scaling the image (i.e. is it a CSS @media query)? It might be possible to draw the path after the re-scale, but again I feel this will need JS as you will need to load the content after the browser load.

Sorry to answer in opposition to what you have asked, but unless there is an alternative I think this is the only way you can do this.